# Processing string to array

Tags: arrays, string, arduino, processing, sensors

I want to read four cyclic measured sensors from an arduino and want to display the values with Processing.

My problem is, I get the error message: "Cannot find a class or type named 'Array' " in my processing code when I want to convert my data string into an array.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;
String Messdaten;
String MessdatenSplit;

void setup () {
  size(500, 500);
  println(Serial.list());
  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);
}

void draw(){
}

void serialEvent(Serial myPort){
    if (myPort.available() > 0){
        String Messdaten = myPort.readStringUntil(3000);
        if (Messdaten != null){
            trim(Messdaten);
            String MessdatenSplit[] = split(Messdaten,",");

            MessdatenSplit = new Array[1400];
            Natrium = new String[350];
            Kalium = new Array[350];
            Lithium = new Array[350];
            Kupfer = new Array[350];

            for (n=0; n<350; n++){
                Natrium[n] = 1+4*n;
            }
            for (k=1; k<350; k++){
                Kalium[k] = 1+4*k;
            }
            for (u=2; u<350; u++){
                Kupfer[u] = 1+4*u;
            }
            for (l=3; l<350; l++){
                Lithium[l] = 1+4*l;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no class named Array (well, there is, but it's not the one you want). That's not how you declare an array.

You declare an array variable by using the type of array you want, then using square brackets []. For example, you're declaring this variable:

```
String MessdatenSplit;
```

This declares the `MessdatenSplit` variable as String, not an array of Strings. Instead, you probably want this:

```
String[] MessdatenSplit;
```

Then when you initialize the `MessdatenSplit` variable, you should again use the type of array it is, and you should also use the square brackets and put the length of the array inside those square brackets. Here you're doing it correctly:

```
Natrium = new String[350];
```

(Although, you're missing a declaration for this variable, so you need to add that in for this to really work.)

The above line creates a String array with 350 indexes. But in this next line, and in a few other places, you're initializing it incorrectly:

```
MessdatenSplit = new Array[1400];
```

There is no `Array` keyword. You need to use the type of array it is, like this:

```
MessdatenSplit = new String[1400];
```

Note that you can also do the variable declaration and initialization in a single line:

```
String[] MessdatenSplit = new String[1400];
```

You might want to start over and declare and initialize a single array variable, then run it to make sure it works. Then add the next array, and run it to see if it works. You're running into trouble because you're trying to write and run your whole sketch at once, when really you need to be testing much smaller steps. Also, you should try to follow standard naming conventions: variables and functions should start with a lower-case letter.